# Use PHP to Display MySQL Results in HTML Table

Tags: php, mysqli

**Update for CodingBiz:**

I'm putting this in my code:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$numRows;$i++) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    $row = $this->fetchAssoc($result);
    $colRow = $this->fetchAssoc($colResult);
    foreach($colRow as $colName) {
        $output .= "<td>".$row[$colName]."</td>";
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
```

in place of

```
for($i=1;$i<=$numRows;$i++) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    $row = $this->fetchAssoc($result);
    for($j=1;$j<=$colNumRows;$j++) {
        $colRow = $this->fetchAssoc($colResult);
        $output .= "<td>".$row[$colRow["COLUMN_NAME"]]."</td>";
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

**Original Post:**

I'm writing a function in a PHP class to display the results of a query in a table. I'm not structuring any of the table myself, I want it everything to be done using PHP. Here is my code so far:

```
function allResults($table,$cols) {
    if(isset($cols)) {
        $query = "SELECT $cols FROM $table";
    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table";
    }
    $result = $this->query($query);
    $numRows =  $this->numRows($result);
    $colQuery ="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='shareride'  AND TABLE_NAME='$table'";
    $colResult = $this->query($colQuery);
    $colNumRows = $this->numRows($colResult);

    $output = '<table class="allResults">';
    $output .= '<tr>';
    for($i=1;$i<=$colNumRows;$i++) {
        $colRow = $this->fetchAssoc($colResult);
        $output .= "<td>".$colRow["COLUMN_NAME"]."</td>";
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
    for($i=1;$i<=$numRows;$i++) {
        $output .= '<tr>';
        $row = $this->fetchAssoc($result);
        for($j=1;$j<=$colNumRows;$j++) {
            $colRow = $this->fetchAssoc($colResult);
            $output .= "<td>".$row[$colRow["COLUMN_NAME"]]."</td>";
        }
        $output .= '</tr>';
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    return $output;
}
```

In case it is unclear, `query` refers to `mysqli_query`, `numRows` refers to `mysqli_num_rows`, and `fetchAssoc` refers to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. The database name is "shareride."

I know I am missing something in this line:

```
$output .= "<td>".$row[$colRow["COLUMN_NAME"]]."</td>";
```

but I just don't know what it is. Right now, I get all the table column titles displayed correctly, and I get the correct number of content rows, but I just can't populate those rows with the actual data from the database.

What am I missing? Any help would be **GREATLY** appreciated!

Comment: i don't understand what youre trying to achieve: if you want to print everything couldn't you do a foreach(column as name=>value) inside a while(row=fetchrow()) ?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to how I should do this? Maybe post your comment as an answer and share the exact code that I should modify? Thanks :)

Comment: @CharlesTian I have made the pieces for you. You can put them all together. It should work with minimal effort. See my update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the data and column names from the same result set

```
  <?php
  $i = 0;
  $colNames = array();
  $data = array();
  while($row = ***_fetch_assoc($res)) //where $res is from the main query result not schema information
  {
     //get the column names into an array $colNames
     if($i == 0) //make sure this is done once
     {
        foreach($row as $colname => $val)
           $colNames[] = $colname;
     }

     //get the data into an array
     $data[] = $row;

     $i++;
  }

 ?>
```

**UPDATE: Suggested by @YourCommonSense to replace the above code and it worked, simple and shorter - A WAY TO GET THE COLUMN NAMES/ARRAY KEYS WITHOUT LOOPING THROUGH LIKE I DID**

```
  $data = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
  {
     $data[] = $row;
  }

  $colNames = array_keys(reset($data))
```

Continued as before: Print the table

```
 <table border="1">
 <tr>
    <?php
       //print the header
       foreach($colNames as $colName)
       {
          echo "<th>$colName</th>";
       }
    ?>
 </tr>

    <?php
       //print the rows
       foreach($data as $row)
       {
          echo "<tr>";
          foreach($colNames as $colName)
          {
             echo "<td>".$row[$colName]."</td>";
          }
          echo "</tr>";
       }
    ?>
 </table>
```

Test Result

[image]

You can see how I separated the data retrieval from table generation. They are dependent of each other now and you can test your table generation without the database by populating the arrays with static data

You can also make them into separate functions.

Comment: What is a better way to approach this? Traditionally one would just specify the table titles manually, but seeing that this is a function I would like to get the titles from the database. And what exactly are custom columns?

Comment: `$query = "SELECT $cols FROM $table";` - custom columns here in which your `$colRow` becomes `explode($cols)` if the column names were separated by commas

Comment: Yes, I haven't gotten to coding that part yet. In that case, I was planning on checking each individual column with the `$cols` variable that I specified, and if the column title was included in `$cols`, display that column, if it wasn't then don't.

Comment: For your answer, would I be placing the foreach statement within `for($j=1;$j<=$colNumRows;$j++) { }`?

Comment: Replace it with foreach. You don't need to know the number of columns anymore

Comment: Maybe I'm just being stupid, but the code still is not functional. I get the number of rows, but I'm not getting any `<td>...</td>` in my source code. Can you kindly take a look at my updated code and see if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: you don't need dedicated half-screen branch to get col names. Simple `$cols = array_keys(reset($data));` is enough

Comment: you're amazing, this helped me a lot

Answer (score 4):

1. **Never** mix your database handling code with HTML output code. These are 2 **totally** different matters. Make your allResults function only return array with data, and then you can make another function to print in fancy way (and **not** in the database handler class).
2. You don't need information schema to get column name - you already have it in the returned array keys.
3. You don't need numRows either - use while() and foreach()
4. **NEVER** insert anything into query directly like you do with `$cols` - eventually it will lead to errors and injections.
5. Such a function, without accepting some parameters for the query, **makes absolutely no sense** especially in the context of migrating from mysql to mysqli - you are going yo use it as an old school mysql query inserting variables, not placeholders. So, it makes migration totally useless.
6. To know "Is there anything wrong with code", one have to **run** it, not watch. Run and debug your code, outputting key variables and making sure you can see errors occurred.

Answer (score 0):

i'd try replacing the data part with something like:

```
while($row = $this->fetchAssoc($colResult))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach($row as $value)
  {
    echo sprintf("<td>%s</td>",$value)
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

i know it's not a proper answer, but it's really hard to read that code imho

Comment: If it's `not a proper answer`, make it a comment?

Comment: well,i think this could be an answer if the topic opener solves the problem with this information.

also i didn't manage to write the code in the comment

Comment: This seems to make my page run in a never-ending loop. Still not getting what I want.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an antipattern.  It should be replaced with the more sensible and concise `printf()`.