# Struggling to get my head around creating PHP Arrays using MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql

This may seem pretty basic to a lot of people but I'm struggling to get my head around this.

I have a MySQL table that looks something like this:

```
| email       | name        | mod1 | mod2 | mod3 | mod4 | mod1r | mod2r | mod3r | mod4r |
| jb@test.com | Joe Bloggs  | 401  | 402  | 405  | 410  | yes   | no    | no    | no    |
| ab@test.com | Alex Baines | 401  | 404  | 407  | 409  | no    | yes   | yes   | no    |
| rs@test.com | Rick Summer | 403  | 406  | 408  | 409  | no    | no    | no    | no    |
```

The last four columns relate to the previous four (so mod1r corresponds to mod1, mod2r to mod2 etc).

What I need to do is twofold:

- 1: Identify which records have  'yes' in one or more of the final four columns
- 2: Identify the data in the preceding four columns that correspond to the 'yes' data.
- 3: Display the results in a table

So in the example above, Rick Summer should be discarded completely as he has no 'yes' data. Joe Bloggs should be displayed once with a value of '401' as he has a yes in the 'mod1r' column and the corresponding value in 'mod1' is '401'. Alex Baines should be displayed twice, once with a value of '404' and again with a value of '407'.

I'd like the final output to look something like this (in an HTML table):

```
| Name        | Module   |
| Joe Bloggs  |  401     |
| Alex Baines |  404     |
| Alex Baines |  407     |
```

Can anyone help? I'm assuming I need to use multidimensional arrays to pull down the data but I'm struggling to figure out how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Little comment: `modXr` seems to be a boolean value. In this case, it would be better to encode it as `0/1`, it will be faster and easier to handle.

Comment: This would be a whole lot easier if your database was [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thanks fedorqui, noted and changes will be made

Comment: Thanks Till - I will do this but still need help in extracting and displaying the relevant values.

Comment: Yeah I'd go for a different db structure as going for a structure like this will make things very complicated. I'd say use a seperate table for the modules, and a seperate table for the module subscriptions. Then `JOIN` your way through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others I would definitely normalize the database structure, so you have three tables instead of one.

users:

```
user_id  email        name
1        jb@test.com  Joe Bloggs
2        ab@test.com  Alex Baines
3        rs@test.com  Rick Summer
```

modules:

```
module_id  modules
1          401
2          402
3          403
4          404
5          405
6          406
7          407
8          408
9          409
10         410
```

users_modules:

```
user_id  module_id
1        1
2        4
2        7
```

This makes it much easier to get the array you want and it avoids future headaches, if you ever need to add more modules. The following query will then return the data in the way you want.

```
SELECT u.name, m.module 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN users_modules um ON u.user_id = um.user_id 
INNER JOIN modules m ON um.module_id = m.module_id
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   select name ,mod1 as module from Table1 where mod1r = 'yes'
  union all
   select name ,mod2 from Table1 where mod2r = 'yes'
  union all
   select name ,mod3 from Table1 where mod3r = 'yes'
   union all
   select name ,mod4  from Table1 where mod4r = 'yes'
```

output:

```
  NAME         MODULE
 Joe Bloggs     401
 Alex Baines    404
 Alex Baines    407
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0497/2)

but to write the whole code , this you should do it your self or take a look here [Use PHP to Display MySQL Results in HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430174/use-php-to-display-mysql-results-in-html-table)  how to build html table with mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Rough implementation idea:

```
For all query results as row:
   For all modules as currentModule:
      if (row[currentModule + 'r']):
         outputLine(row['name'], row[currentModule]);
```

Although you really should consider removing those module columns from the table and create a table with columns `user_id` and `module_id` instead. They you could do something like this and would get your result directly from the database:

```
SELECT    u.name, m.module_id module
FROM      users u
JOIN      users2modules m ON u.id = m.user_id
ORDER BY  u.name ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Till, so once I've made the changes to the database, what do I do then?