# Echo MySQL result as column heading? in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a list of dates in a table, I want to output them using php as Column names

So if the table has values 1,2 and 3

I want to create a table that will have 3 columns and 1,2 and 3 as column names

Comment: Both too broad and unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use the mysql results as column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function db_select_with_col()
{
$rows = array();
$result = db_query("SELECT
student.StudentID,
student.`Name`,
attendance.Date,
CASE WHEN attendance.StudentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Present' ELSE 'Absent' END as Attendance_Status
FROM
student
Left JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID
WHERE
attendance.Date = '2015-03-30'");

// If query failed, return `false`
if ($result === false) {
    return false;
}


// If query was successful, retrieve all the rows into an array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$colNames = array_keys(reset($rows));

foreach ($colNames as $colName) {
    echo "<th>$colName</th>";
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($colNames as $colName) {
        echo "<td>" . $row[$colName] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
}

?>
```

Figured out how to do it thanks to the answer [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14430366/4680117)