# Php script to display checkbox and update database

Tags: php

I have the following code to query the database for fields hostname, notifier and print it out in a table.

```
$host = "test.xxxx.com";
$user = "host";
$pass = "xxxx";
$db = "hosts";

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect!");

mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Unable to select database!");

$owner = $_GET['owner'];
$query = "SELECT `host`,`notifier` FROM `hosts` where `owner`='$owner'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());

echo "<form method='post' action='#'>";
$len = mysql_num_fields($result);
$tempString =  "<html><body><table border='2'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++)
{$tempString = $tempString.'<th>'.mysql_fetch_field($result)->name.'</th>';}
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{$tempString = $tempString.'</tr><tr>';
foreach($row as $cell)
{$tempString = $tempString.'<td>'.(($cell==null) ? '<input type="checkbox">Null field</input>' : $cell).'</td>';}
}
 $tempString = $tempString.'</td></tr></table></body></html>';
 echo $tempString;
 echo "</tbody></table><input type='submit' value='submit'></form>";
```

How can I include the following code to update my database table with a "Y" based on the checked value with value in the check box?

```
 $cell = N;
 if(isset($_POST['cell']) and $_POST['cell']==1) {
  $cell = Y;
}
   $query = mysql_query("UPDATE `hosts`.`hosts` SET `notifier`='$cell' WHERE `host`='$name';") or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: I got that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355780/echo-mysql-result-as-column-heading-in-php :)

Comment: unless you want to utilize the checkbox component of the input box, i would use an image.

Comment: I do want to utilize the checkbox component to update my database. If the user checks the checkbox and clicks submit, I want that to update the database field with a Y.

Comment: @LarryWhite the link you provided does not `echo` `th` in the `tr`.

Comment: I dont know about what your columns choices are, but i would make sure you cover all the cases.  Example, if it is a boolean (shown by the chk box) it would be 1,0,null.   Whereas, 0 and null should prolly be "unchecked"  and then youcould do smething like:  `$val = isset($_POST('myname')) ? 1: 0;`  then carry out your update as:   'update table A set ..., and myBool = $val where B = C;'

Comment: if it is not checked, it will not send it with the REQUEST at all...  soo... thats a thing

Comment: something like this? $publish = FALSE;
if(isset($_POST['publish']) and $_POST['publish']==1) {
  $publish = TRUE;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Using <th> inside <tr> works - that creates a table header
```

You've got two basic choices to get the checkbox into your html. One is to create the html via the echo process you're using. Your if statement would go into the foreach loop to create the checkbox if the value from your db is null. You'll want to name each checkbox using the id= element in your html. Each checkbox will require a unique id, so that you can reference it later on (e.g. id="CB_nnn", where nnn is a value from 000 to whatever is your max). 
You then either add all of the id's to your submit button statement, or you write some javascript to gather all of the unique id's together to then send the data back.

It may be simpler, although it starts harder, to package your data from your db as a JSON stream or as an XML stream and manage it for the user via javascript. That will give you a better separation of your data model (from the db) and the View portion of your app. This would be a simple application of the MVC - Model/View/Controller pattern. 

 this approach would allow you to have a portion of your javascript solely dedicated to creating the User Interface and a separate set of services for managing the data movement between your php code and the UI.

The following code will create a table, header and evaluate each field for presence of a null value returned by the DB engine (mysql in this case).  The ternary operator (the "?" operator) will either display the value of the returned data or will display a checkbox with the text "null field" next to it.

```
$len = mysql_num_fields($resultSet);
$tempString =  "<html><body><table border='2'><tr>";
for($i=0; $i<$len; $i++)
 {$tempString = $tempString.'<th>'.mysql_fetch_field($resultSet)->name.'</th>';}
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultSet, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {$tempString = $tempString.'</tr><tr>';
 foreach($row as $cell)
 {$tempString = $tempString.'<td>'.(($cell==null) ? '<input type="checkbox">Null field</input>' : $cell).'</td>';}
 }
 $tempString = $tempString.'</td></tr></table></body></html>';
 echo $tempString;
```

Comment: Can you please edit my post with the if statement in the for loop? I tried inserting in two of the for loops and I am still not getting it? I understand Perl very well, but php seems a little off or may be I am new to it.

Comment: Hi Bob, I have changed my original script. Please check and let me know if this works.

Comment: I have made changes to my original post. Now, all that is left is do is add the submit option and make it update my database with a query based on if the checkbox was check or not. I have some sample code. Can you please check if that will do?

Comment: Larry, your current code specifies that all checkboxes will have an id of "id[]". You probably want to change the name="id[]" to name="id_'.$row_id.'"' so that each checkbox will have a unique ID. otherwise you won't be able to identify which were checked and which were not checked. You then need to add the checkbox id's to your submit statement so that they can be passed back to a receiving php file.

Comment: Larry, for what it's worth, I handle these kinds of requirements in JavaScript rather than in php because it give me more flexibility in how I handle the UI, move data around, and notify the server of an update. You can, in JavaScript, for example, monitor checkboxes for status changes and then do something dynamic with the UI - put up a small window to get more info - and asynchronously contact the server to update or query for more data. It makes your site appear faster without having to put a heavy-duty server in place. I use XML (old school) for data exchange; JSON would be better.